# Device Pixel Ratio and CSS pixel on different screen size

Tags: css, pixel

The **reference pixel** (*CSS pixel*) is defined as:

> [...] the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm’s length.

This definition seems pretty easy, but I'm not really sure that I got it.

**QUESTION 1**

I noticed that my laptop monitor and TV screen have the same
DPR (= 1) although the former is a 15'' screen with 1366x768 and the latter a 50'' screen with 1920x1080. If the DPR expresses the relation between CSS pixel and physical pixels, shouldn't the latter be bigger? According to the CSS pixel definition it should be bigger because the TV screen is supposed to be watch far away.

**QUESTION 2**

Do screen vendors apply the definition of CSS pixel?